# Python import calendar error

Tags: python-2.7

I was doing tutorial from tutorialspoint about calendar

---

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import calendar

cal = calendar.month(2008, 1)
print "Here is the calendar:"

print cal
```

---

Above code throw the following error,

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "./datetime.py", line 2, in <module>
    import calendar
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/calendar.py", line 9, in <module>
    import datetime
  File "/Users/aungyin/workplace/python/datetime.py", line 4, in <module>
    cal = calendar.month(2008, 1)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'month'
```

is it because of environment problem?

python is set to "/usr/local/bin/python" in $PATH

I am using Mac with Python of version 2.7.10.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code works for me, although you probably don't have two statements in one line. Don't name your file as `datetime.py`, your module name is in conflict with the prepackaged `datetime` module. Also, don't forget to remove the `pyc` file generated (It will be in the same directory as your source code file).

Comment: thanks @EagerNoob, I renamed file name to test.py. it still doesn't work. I got the same error.

Answer (score 1):

Probably,you are giving the filename as **datetime.py** and so python compiler would treat as a new file. But in line **import datetime** ,compiler gets confused with the name of the file you gave(importing the same file you are in).
So,change the filename for the desired behaviour like this

### filename test_tutorials.py

```
 import calendar
 import datetime
 cal = calendar.month(2008, 1) print "Here is the calendar:"
 print cal
```

O/p   Here is the calendar:
      January 2008
Mo Tu We Th Fr Sa Su
    1  2  3  4  5  6
 7  8  9 10 11 12 13
14 15 16 17 18 19 20
21 22 23 24 25 26 27
28 29 30 31

Comment: Thankz @anoop, I change file name to test.py and delete .pyc file from project directory. I works now.

Comment: @aungyin,If you find this answer useful,you can upvote the answer and mark it as final answer ! :-)